# Create a panel of 5x5 random numbers

Tags: python

The assignment says that I have to create a panel of random numbers 5x5 and calculate the sum of the numbers per line, per pile and calculate the sum of numbers of the diagonal of the panel. The results must be saved in a text file.
It would be very helpfull if you solve this with the command "for".

For example like this code:

```
import random

randnumb = []   
for i in range(10):   
    line= []
    for j in range(4):
        line.append(random.randint(1,1000))    
    randnumb.append(line)    
a=open("a.txt","w")  
for i in range(10):    
    g=""   
    for j in range(4):    
        g += str(randnumb[i][j])+ " " 
    g += "\n"  
    a.write(g)   
a.close()    
a=open("a.txt","r")    
print(a.read())    
a.close()
```

Comment: Please add your attempt to solve this problem. It is best if you ask about a small part of the code, rather than asking for the entire code.

Comment: Why range(10) and range(4)? How are they related to a 5x5 array?

Comment: this is just an example, it's not the assignment

Answer (score 0):

I used `for` but you can replace it for a `map`, if you want.

```
import random

# generates 5 x 5 random matrix
random.seed(23)
a = [[random.random() for _ in range(5)] for x in range(5)]

rowSums = [sum(row) for row in a] # for each row ... sum the numbers in the list...
columnSums = [sum(col) for col in zip(*a)] # for each column ... sum the numbers in the list...
diagonalSum = sum([a[i][i] for i in range(len(a))])

# print results
print rowSums
# [3.4414822773841207, 1.720709091012754, 1.4966213860156654, 2.084642254225464, 3.621865231749428]

print columnSum
# [2.7740025507928237, 3.035484154123261, 2.4396250416690193, 1.3413097355704942, 2.774898758231834]

print diagonalSum
# 2.8094518166
```